# Buscador JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Para buscar en un `TableView` que usan filtered o directamente en la sentencia sql.

Comment: Lo explicas muy bien: *lo que me hace dudar es que si se diera el caso que fueran cientos de miles de registros (en mi trabajo se da el caso incluso millones), ralentizaria mucho ya que **no limito la info en la consulta***. Entonces ponle límites.

Comment: Al ponerle limites, no mostraría todos los valores y seria un solución a medias, ya que habría que realizar otra vez una consulta para mostrar el resto de datos.

Comment: Mientras sigas en esta línea la pregunta va a seguir cerrada. ¿Qué opción es mejor? Depende de cada caso y ese es el motivo por el que muy seguramente tu pregunta siga cerrada. Otra cosa es que expongas un caso concreto lo suficientemente conciso como para que una de esas posibilidades gane peso sobre las demás. A modo de ejemplo: no es lo mismo que la query devuelva 10 casos que varios millones...

Comment: Imagina que busques "gato" en google. Tiene millones de resultados pero en la barra de auto completar solo muestra 5 y los resultados los muestra paginados a pesar de tener millones de millones de opciones

Comment: Pues la verdad que no se como realizar la pregunta para que parezca correcta. Y creo que es bastante interesante, ya que con la tecnología JavaFX he recurrido a la metodología que usaba en java swing.